# I got error on apache2 server django application Failed to proxy response from daemon

Tags: django, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-22.04

The website works fine only for 1-2 requests, after which it starts loading endlessly and if I wait for some time I get an Internal Server Error.
After this I reload the server `sudo systemctl reload apache2`, website works for 1 request and I got same problem again
(When i use `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it works fine)

I use Django application on Ubuntu 22.04

Using `apache2` and `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

Libapache version is:
`libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 4.9.0-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]`

Python version 3.10.12

My Apache file conf `etc/apache2/apache.conf` (I added here only `Servername` and `LimitRequestFieldSize`)

```
ServerName caspian-bavarians.com

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf


<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent


IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

LimitRequestFieldSize 32768
```

My website conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerName caspian-bavarians.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

  Alias /static /home/ftpuser/caspi/static
  <Directory /home/ftpuser/caspi/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /media /home/ftpuser/caspi/media
  <Directory /home/ftpuser/caspi/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory /home/ftpuser/caspi/main>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias /  /home/ftpuser/caspi/main/wsgi.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/ftpuser/caspi/ python-home=/home/ftpuser/venv
  WSGIProcessGroup django_app
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache error log

`[Fri Sep 22 05:38:30.466675 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6140:tid 140592497751616] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 82.194.20.184:60468] mod_wsgi (pid=6140): Failed to proxy response from daemon., referer: http://www.caspian-bavarians.com/az/cars/ [Fri Sep 22 05:38:34.918090 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6139:tid 140592497751616] [client 82.194.20.184:57353] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'django_app': /home/ftpuser/caspi/main/wsgi.py, referer: http://www.caspian-bavarians.com/az/car/mercedes-benz-e220-7/ [Fri Sep 22 05:38:34.918108 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6139:tid 140592480966208] [client 82.194.20.184:57024] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'django_app': /home/ftpuser/caspi/main/wsgi.py, referer: http://www.caspian-bavarians.com/az/cars/ [Fri Sep 22 05:50:33.804640 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6139:tid 140592298276416] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 82.194.20.184:63960] mod_wsgi (pid=6139): Failed to proxy response from daemon., referer: http://www.caspian-bavarians.com/az/cars/ [Fri Sep 22 05:50:37.371732 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6139:tid 140592506144320] [client 82.194.20.184:58025] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'django_app': /home/ftpuser/caspi/main/wsgi.py, referer: http://www.caspian-bavarians.com/az/car/mercedes-benz-e220-7/ [Fri Sep 22 05:50:38.194056 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6140:tid 140592323454528] [client 82.194.20.184:63962] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'django_app': /home/ftpuser/caspi/main/wsgi.py, referer: http://www.caspian-bavarians.com/az/car/mercedes-benz-e220-7/ [Fri Sep 22 05:50:38.742344 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6139:tid 140592357025344] [client 159.203.17.7:44390] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'django_app': /home/ftpuser/caspi/main/wsgi.py`

My wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for main project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This version of my application works fine on heroku

- I tried `apt-get update` and `upgrade`
- Checked the version of `libapache-mod-wsqi-py3`
- Tried reboot the system
- Disable and then Enable the website

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: Add this line to your apache config file (which, in my case, is etc/apache2/apache.conf):

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: Had the same issue and wanted to know what the line is doing. This is the answer I found:
This directive instructs mod_wsgi to run the WSGI application in the global interpreter, rather than in a daemon process group. This can be important in certain situations, particularly when your Python application relies on global variables or shared resources that need to be accessible across multiple requests or threads.